# UBUNTU 9.10: Unable to install packages due to broken packages

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall

I have not been able to install new packages in Ubuntu since the linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-17-generic package is broken...

```
   I get the following errors while installing any package....I had once been stupid enough to delete the /lib/modules/2.6.28-17 directory while removing the 2.6.28-17 kernel files, Instead of uninstalling it. Is there any way to rectify (work around) this problem...How would it be if I simply try to recreate the file structure in /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-17-generic.postrm, Just a suggestion, would it work???  Please help me out!!!
```

---

```
   Removing linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-17-generic ...
```

rmdir: failed to remove `/lib/modules/2.6.28-17-generic/volatile/': No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not open '/boot/System.map-2.6.28-17-generic': No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.28-17-generic
Cannot find /lib/modules/2.6.28-17-generic
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-2.6.28-17-generic
dpkg: error processing linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-17-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-17-generic

### E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Thanks a lot,
Avinash.

Comment: Does this help? apt-get -f install

Comment: No it does not...tried it yesterday & i got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a package's `prerm` or `postrm` script fails, often your best bet is to edit the script in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` and comment out (or sometimes tweak) the failing lines. You should review carefully what those lines are doing and try to manually do what they attempted to do.

In your case, you've already deleted the files that the script is trying to delete, so comment out the failing lines in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-17-generic.postrm` and run `dpkg --remove linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-17-generic`.

Once you've removed the offending package, run `apt-get -f install` to finish any package management operation (install, configure, remove, …) that was waiting on the removal.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, for the reply. I'll just try that...